# Two Seperate WHERE clauses in a DELETE Function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to perform a DELETION on certain Transactions that were made between the first day of the current month and the last day of the month. The deletion process shall ONLY be made once the FileUploadDate reaches the last day of the month. In other words when the FileUploadDate is EQUAL to the last day of the month. The main issue here is when the first condition of the WHERE clause is TRUE, the second condition is "Filtered" with values from the first condition, which makes it irrelevant.  I tried using other methods such as CASE-WHEN-THEN, but I'm having problems integrating DELETE inside a CASE clause (if that is even possible). Is there a way to perform two separate conditions without one affecting the other? Thanks.

```
DELETE 
FROM   transacions 
WHERE  EXISTS 
       ( 
            SELECT 
            * 
            FROM transacions 
                WHERE fileuploaddate = CONVERT(      date, dateadd(d, -2, dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, getdate())                                                                        + 1, 0)),103)
                    AND fileuploaddate BETWEEN CONVERT(date, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0)) 
                    AND    CONVERT(date, dateadd(d, -1, dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, getdate()) + 1, 0)),103)
        )
```

Comment: The subquery needs a condition with reference to the outer table.

Comment: Are you going to run this statement once a month (on the last day) or are you going to run it more often and you want it only to delete transactions, if it's run on the last day of the month?

Comment: The file upload is performed everyday, hence the FileUploadDate, however that is a seperate component. The above scrip will indeed run every day to check whether the FileUploadDate is equal to the last month of the day. If that condition is true. All transactions of that month needs to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `OR` instead `AND`

```
WHERE FileUploadDate = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(d, -2, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)),103)
               OR   FileUploadDate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) AND CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)),103)
```

Comment: I tried using OR before, but I also want to check if the FileUploadDate is equal to the last day of the month before deleting. With OR it completely ignores the first condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELETE 
  FROM Transactions
 WHERE EOMONTH (FileUploadDate)  = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0) -- delete on the last day of the month
   AND FileUploadDate >= DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0)  -- delete files from the begining of the month
   AND FileUploadDate <= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0) -- delete files to the end of the current montn
```